# what is the proper proxy settings for docker and kubernetes

Tags: docker, proxy, kubernetes

Behind the enterprise proxy,

what is the proper setting for kubernetes (and docker)?

1. when set the http_proxy, https_proxy, no_proxy

`export http_proxy="http://1.2.3.4:8080"`

or

`export http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:8080`

or

`export http_proxy=1.2.3.4:8080`

2. Should I set capital environment variable like HTTP_PROXY ?
3. When I set no_proxy,

`export no_proxy=10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3`

(all the kubernetes master and nodes )

or

`export no_proxy=10.0.0.*`

4. Should I setting below file ?

   $ vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
   [Service]
   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4:8080" "HTTPS_PROXY=http://1.2.3.4:8080" "NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost,10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3"

In this file, applied same rule with above question?

5. any other considerations?

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We always include the scheme in our environment variables.

/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export http_proxy=http://<proxy>:3128
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
export no_proxy=169.254.169.254,localhost,127.0.0.1
export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
export NO_PROXY=$no_proxy
```

/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://<proxy>:3128/" "HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy>:3128/"
```

Answer (score 0):

we will add the proxy in both /etc/environment file and docker.service file

In /etc/environment

```
export http_proxy=http://10.169.33.81:8080/

export https_proxy=http://10.169.33.81:8080/
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1,localhost,(added all the worker node server ip)"
export NO_PROXY=$no_proxy
```

In docker.service file

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://10.x.x.x:8080/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.x.x.x:8080/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0"
```